# How to use XSLT on XMLs which have dynamic number of columns to get result as a HTML table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, html-table

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rowset>
    <Row>
    <Column1>1381.00000</Column1>
    <Column2>9851.00000</Column2>
    <Column3>10.00000</Column3> 
    <Column4>130253.00000</Column4>
    <Column5>8065.88235</Column5>
    </Row> </rowset>
```

Some other xml have different number of columns like this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rowset>
    <Row>
    <Column1>1551.00000</Column1>
    <Column2>977.00000</Column2>
    <Column3>9.00000</Column3>
    </Row></rowset>
```

Here is something which i have tried, but which works for only xml records which has 3 columns, I want to make it dynamic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>Metric Validator</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th>Column1</th>
                  <th>Column2</th>
                  <th>Column3</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="rowset/Row">
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Column1" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Column2" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Column3" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <xsl:for-each select="rowset/Row[1]/*">
   <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
  </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="rowset/Row">
  <tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

Comment: this will print the table values. but table header will not be dynamic this way

Comment: thats perfect @Jens Teich